# Importing a file c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a code that takes a number from a user, and makes that the size of an array. Then I fill the array with strings from a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    cout << "Please input a number: " << endl;
    
    int size;
    
    cin >> size;
    
    string* myList = new string[size];

    
    string lucky = "luckyseven.txt";
    ifstream luckyFile;
    luckyFile.open(lucky.c_str());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        luckyFile >> myList[i];
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cout << myList[j] << endl;
    }
    
    luckyFile.close();
    
    delete [] myList;

    return 0;

}
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS8RU.png)

I am able to input a number, but after, the array is just blank. I believe I am doing something wrong with the importing a file section
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Where's your error handling on the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like your file does not exist, and you haven't done any error handling here

```cpp
ifstream luckyFile;
luckyFile.open(lucky.c_str());
if (luckyFile.is_open()) {
    // your code here
} else {
    // handle error
    cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! Totally forgot about that.

Comment: Great, if it helped you could you accept the answer.

Comment: Done! Sorry didn't do that before, new to this.